# OpenCV: function arguments useful for what?

Tags: python, opencv

I do not understand this code taken from OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html#mouse-handling):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),100,(255,0,0),-1)

# Create a black image, a window and bind the function to window
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

Specifically, I do not understand why the parameters of  the `draw_circle()` function are that way but never used later. Can someone explain to me what's behind that, please?

Comment: Because *"Creating mouse callback function has a specific format which is same everywhere."* - those are the parameters the callback passes (adding or removing parameters will cause a `TypeError`), you just don't need all of them *for this simple example*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you, but [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#setmousecallback) I do not find what can explain  the format of `draw_circle()` method. if you can give me a link it will be nice

Comment: Do you mean *"what can `flags` and `param` be used for?*"? I don't know - if there isn't sufficient information in the documentation, see the section at the bottom of the page you originally linked, which provides links to their Q&A forum and bug reporting. You could also look at e.g. http://opencv-srf.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/mouse-events.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you very much for the link, it makes things clear  about those arguments

Answer (score -3):

Bellow my code is working fine just check it out..

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1=cv2.imread('Image/Desert.jpg')       
def draw(event,x,y,flage,param):
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.circle(img1,(x,y),4,(0,0,0),4)
        cv2.namedWindow('Image')
        cv2.setMouseCallback('Image',draw)
    while(1):
        cv2.imshow('Image',img1)
        if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF ==27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.